# How to define a relay in a device tree

Tags: embedded-linux, device-tree

I have a board, SoC running Linux 5+, with a electrical relay. The relay is triggered by a GPIO. I am looking for a good way to define a relay in a device tree file.

I define LEDs as

```dts
led {
    compatible = "gpio-leds";
    debug {
        label = "debug";
        gpios = ...
        default-state = "off";
    };
};
```

This results in

```sh
# ls /sys/class/leds/
debug
```

I would like to have the relay be something similar such as

```sh
# ls /sys/class/{relays,outputs,gpios}/
relay1
```

What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks. I do name them via "gpio-line-names". However the names act like a label when I interact through the device API. I imagined having the GPIOs in sysfs like "leds". Maybe I am just approaching this from the wrong angle.

Comment: Again thank you. I think that is sufficient for an answer. I.e. avoid sysfs, use `gpio-line-names`, and interact via newer character device API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since relay behaves as simply as GPIO output (or more precisely GPO), what you need is just name the corresponding line. It can be done by assigning `gpio-line-names` property of the GPIO controller in the ACPI or Device Tree. With a use of `libgpiod` tools (such as `gpiofind`, `gpioinfo`), that access GPIO controller via character device node, you may find your line and do the operations on it. Note, GPIO sysfs interface is deprecated and it will be removed from the kernel on a horizon of ~5 years or so.

Comment: Removal seems overdue, see this [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/fe95046e960b4b76e73dc1486955d93f47276134)