# Name GPIO array in device tree and echo value from sysfs

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, gpio, device-tree

I am very new to porting Linux, and I am wondering if there is a way to configure an array GPIO bits in the device tree to show up in sysfs (or wherever is most appropriate)?

I want to be able to read the value of a 8-bit dip switch connected to GPIOs by `echo`-ing a file rather than having to write more elaborate code. This does not seem like a novel concept, which leads me to believe there is a way to do this; much like how LEDs are managed in the device tree.

I would suspect it would show up somewhere in `/sys/class/*/` and be a file named after my entry in the device tree, such as "dip-switch" and then calling `echo dip-switch` would print out the value of the switch.

If I am making a fundamental misunderstanding, any guidance on best practices is welcome.

I have read through a lot of documentation and have not figured out how to do this. For what its worth, I am working with an NXP iMX8 chip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a relay in a device tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761782/how-to-define-a-relay-in-a-device-tree)

Comment: See [a set of gpios to be decoded to a number](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/gpio-decoder.txt)

Comment: @0andriy that is close to what I want, but it seems to only work for 1 bit, and I'm looking for something for n-bits.

Comment: @ReAl I attempted the decoder option, but when I tested it, my echo just sat blocking. I had difficulty finding more comprehensive documentation online of how to configure/use the gpio decoder. It seems to be the closest to what I want though.

Comment: You can always create an aggregator (virtual) GPIO chip out of any pins available in the system. In this new GPIO chip your DIP switch always will be the only one and the pins will correspond directly 1:1 on what switches are. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/gpio/gpio-aggregator.html That will be **exactly** what you want (I truly believe).

Comment: @0andriy I think what you linked to is almost exactly what I'm looking for. I wanted to be able to read the entire dip switch as an 8-bit value, but this might be the closest I can get. I can't try and test it just yet, but I think I can be satisfied with this solution.

Comment: In the kernel there is an API `gpiod_get_array()`. There is also possibility to call it from user space, e.g. `gpioget gpiochip0 1 2 3 4`. Note, in either case you do not need GPIO aggregator. although it will help when the pins are from different GPIO chips.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you! I think it's safe to say my question is answered @0andriy. If you could submit an answer that would be fantastic.